# Matrix Indexing with larger matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

I'm trying to understand some old code from a predecessor and I'm having some problems with a certain kind of matrix indexing:

I have a large matrix `A` that has labelled regions (neighboring elements that share a number)
Now I have a second matrix `B=[0 1 2 3 ... n]` with `n` being the number of elements
Then we access `output = B(A+1)`.
Now I don't really get what happens when I try to index a smaller matrix with a larger one. And then I don't see that `output` is any different from my matrix `A`.

Anybody can help me with my confusion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing a small vector using a large matrix is a (nice) way of performing a look-up-table operation:  that is `output` is generated by replacing each element of `A` by the element `B(A+1)` the result is the same size as `A`.
In your particular example, since `B( A(ii,jj)+1 ) == A(ii,jj)` for all `ii` and `jj`, this specific look-up operation is meaningless.

You can try different `B` vectors and see how that change influence `output`.

Comment: Ah thanks. Can you explain what Matlab is actually doing when I index a smaller vector with a larger matrix?

Comment: @DarkCell the result of `B(A+1)` assigns, for each element of `A`, the output `B(A(ii,jj)+1)`. the output is thus of size `A`.